# Remove characters from a string teradata

Tags: string, teradata

How can i remove using teradata query all other characters except 15 from string {"Here we start":"15","My Id":1}
It should return only 15

thanks

Comment: What version of Teradata are you using?

Comment: Why do you expect **15** and not **151**? Do you want exactly 15 or also 51 or 111?

Comment: I managed to do this .Thanks Guys